# --add-exports module/package=ALL-UNNAMED

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I'm new in Java. While configuring IntellIJ this pops up when I try to set up JavaFX, I wrote:

```
--add-exports <module>/<package>=ALL-UNNAMED
```

To the configurations in Run/Debug. I don't know what's the problem,

I tried to write:

```
--module-path /.../javafx-sdk-21.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

But I get the errors to

Comment: Try following the appropriate directions over at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ for setting up a JavaFX project.

Comment: Also see the [Idea JavaFX documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).